# Apache have shared objects for both windows and linux.How do they do it?

Tags: c++, apache2, shared-objects

Apache have .so modules for both windows and linux.How do they do it?

Comment: isnt this the same question regarding dll and so?

use libtool

Comment: What do you mean "how do they do it?" The windows versions are compiled on windows and the linux ones on linux. Both use a portability library, the Apache Portable Runtime (APR).

Comment: same,but rehashed,i asked this question when in previous question was answers like "this is impossible"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, I would suspect they remain dynamic link libraries with different file extensions but I could be wrong. File extension, is, after all, no guarantee of file type. If depends.exe in the Windows SDK can parse them, they're dlls. I have never tried and now can't, no Windows on my pc anymore.

Edit: looking at this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_so.html#creating it looks like it is just a naming convention - "Apache still loads .dlls..."

Comment: Yes the Windows .so files are DLLs. There is nothing magical about the .DLL extension - you could give Windows DLLs the extension .MyLittlePony and Windows would still be happy.

Comment: Another +1 for .MyLittlePony - I am well aware file extensions are meaningless for file type since I use linux mostly, however, I wasn't sure if the use of a different file extension signified anything different... as it turns out not, but gotta be careful.